# Resize Image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi friends I am trying to resize an image using javascript

Problem:  I am losing a part of the image while trying to do so (ie only getting image upto 305 and 210):

```
 theImg=new Image(); 
 theImg.height = "305";
 theImg.width = "210";
```

(original ht:360 width:480 of the image which I am trying to scale)

http://postimg.org/image/69ea8dvb9/  is one image

and http://postimg.org/image/9kawwqmpf/ is the other ..

We can see that second is not similar to the first one. The image looks as if it is cropped

not resized.

Comment: you're setting the size yourself, what do you mean by "losing" ?

Comment: can you give us some screenshots ?

Comment: Also, try `theImg.style.height="305"` & `theImg.style.width="210"`

Comment: It should scale down with what you have. But why are you scaling it down like that.. it will distort it, unless that is the idea.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/9kawwqmpf/ is one image and http://postimg.org/image/69ea8dvb9/ is the other image ... as u can see second one is the full one where as the first one doesnt have the complete pic

Comment: Looks like there is a lot more code involved.. it is not just one image but 12 or something?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem you're having here is that your aspect ratio doesn't match.  You're starting at 1.33:1 and converting to .69:1.

Normally this would mean that your image gets distorted.  In your case, the image is getting cropped.

Comment: He says he's losing part of it. That means it's getting cropped.  He even says "The image looks as if it is cropped". In any case, the aspect ratio is WAY off, which is what the problem is. People are too free with the downvotes around here.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I have Attached Images for which I am facing the problem .. please can u solve my issue.

Comment: I think I already have, as far as I can. The image you have is shaped one way, and your destination is completely different. (your image is Landscape, and you are making it portrait.)  You'd be best to bring you image into PS or something, and size it correctly. You're going to have to deal with some cropping.